# Personalisation based on current or previous visited pages

Tags: personalization

I am looking to implement some basic personalisation on our site. Our business services multiple sectors. The page hierarchy looks a little like this:

- Home
- Aerospace

  - Aero Wings
  - Aero Cockpits
- Cars
- Trains
- Busses

We have a banner on the home page which shows a generic welcome message and image. I would like to personalise this banner to show an aeroplane picture and message if the user has **ever** visited either the aerospace page, or aerospace child pages.

I can see this rule which is close:

> where the specific page has been visited during the current visit

However I would like to expand this to include past/previous visits.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you can tag your visitors during past/current interactions and then use "when the current contact has registered the {something} during any interaction" rule to do personalization.

You can tag your visitors by triggering goal, outcome or similar event triggered during their visit of aerospace and child pages.

For your scenario best would be to create either Goal or Outcome where rule will be specified like this:
"where the item template is specific template".
You will put here two rules that item template is 'aerospace page template' **OR** item template is 'aerospace child pages template'.

[image: Rule Goal]

See more information here on how to tag visitors and then do personalization:

http://www.coreblimeysitecore.com/blog/tagging-your-visitors-with-sitecore-8/

Comment: Thank you this sounds almost perfect. Unfortunately our aerospace pages use the same 'general template' as every other page ont he site. Is there another condition you can think of that I could use to set a goal?

Comment: Then best option would be to create your custom rule similarly to the 'Where the item template is specific template' but yours would be 'Where the item path contains value' where value for you would be '/sitecore/content/aerospace/'. This would overcome your limitations. Take a look on this rule /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Item Information/Item Template and create similar one

Comment: Decompile code from Sitecore.Kernel.dll and find Sitecore.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.WhenTemplateIs. Use dotPeek or ILSpy tools

Comment: This one could be also good inspiration - Sitecore.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.ItemNameCondition also from Sitecore.Kernel.dll

Comment: @Mike - Does this help you?

Comment: I do not have dev access to the site, but I will try your first suggestion above tomorrow, thanks